# Imputation with Observation

Tags: data-imputation, measurement-error

How does one combine imputation of a value with an observation of that value?

A consequent question:

When the values that would be imputed (if they were missing) differ greatly from the observed values, is there a procedure for quantitatively/probabilistically assigning error/blame to the data sources?

To further elaborate the question:

If a value is missing, imputation ideally derives a probability *distribution* for that value.  A single value is then often, but not always, chosen from that distribution (as though it had been observed).

Any actual observation involves some uncertainty.  Therefore an observed value is also a probability *distribution*.

When imputation of a value is done, as well as observation of that value, how are their respective *distributions* combined?

Comment: How to impute depends on the type of analysis being considered, Multiple imputation usually will handle the problem.

Comment: You wrote " how are their respective distributions combined?" , which distributions  do you mean ? there is just one distribution (posterior predictive distribution ) which reflects the uncertainty regarding the possible values and from  which we take random draws , we combine the estimates not the "distributions " [See this link][1]


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192061/framework-of-multiple-imputation/192071#192071

Comment: One distribution is (as you point out) from that linked question: "these plausible values are drawn from a distribution specifically modeled for each missing entry".  The other distribution is for the actually measured entry (not missing) based on any information available about the measurement of that entry, such as accuracy of the measurement instrument.