# How to deal with missing values?

Tags: missing-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a question regarding exploratory data analysis, specifically, how to deal with missing values. Here is a toy dataset to describe my question:
[image]

In exploring each variable (a frequency table showing the number of movies for each genre, mean/SD of revenue and tickets), should I use 1)different data subsets for each, or 2)an identical dataset for all?
That is,

1. a subset that dropped id 203, 207 for the genre frequency data, a subset without 205, 210 in talking about the revenue, .... OR
2. one subset that dropped 203, 204, 205, 207, 210 for the all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on many parameters: purpose of your analysis, sample size, frequency of missing values, ultimate goal, descriptive vs inference study, etc...

For instance, if you want to study the revenue by movie, then you can ignore those with NaN values because you cannot describe information that you do not have. But if you want to draw conclusions (inference) on revenue by genre and your sample size is very small, then the quality of your study might be impacted by these NaN values. You will also need to answer questions such as: "can these movies with genre "NaN" be grouped together as "Other" or are they the result of missing information?" Answering this question will lead to different approaches to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you really only do the table and statistics that you mention, option 1 should be fine, but also list the number of missing values per variable. If you want to do more sophisticated stuff, things become more complicated, and I agree with the answer by Pitouille. It all depends on what you ultimately want to find out and do, also numbers of missing values and whether they are "randomly" distributed over variables and cases or whether they concentrate on some of them are important for deciding what to do. (It is for example important what percentage of cases you "lose" in options 1 and 2.)

Note also that there are more options for dealing with missing values such as (multiple) imputation.

Comment: To complement @lewian on multiple imputation, a starting point could be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192061/framework-of-multiple-imputation